# Defining a custom loss function in Tensorflow that uses another function

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, loss-function

Ive been hitting my head against the wall with this for a couple of days now.

I have a tensorflow model. I have also defined a custom loss function for it to train with. The function inside the loss function requires the input to be a numpy array. But whenever I try to run the program it returns me an error indicating that the tensor cannot be transformed to a numpy.

This is the code for the loss function:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    :param y_true: true list of coordinates of the control points in the format of the nn
    :param y_pred: predicted list of coordinates of the control points in the format of the nn
    :return: mean root square error of the position of the points of the generated bezier curve from the control points
    """
    #control_true = [list(pair) for pair in zip(y_true[::2], y_true[1::2])]
    #control_pred = [list(pair) for pair in zip(y_pred[::2], y_pred[1::2])]

    control_true = tf.reshape(y_true, (-1, 2))
    control_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, (-1, 2))

    true_bezier_x, true_bezier_y = bezier_curve(control_true.numpy())
    pred_bezier_x, pred_bezier_y = bezier_curve(control_pred.numpy())

    error_x = true_bezier_x - pred_bezier_x
    error_y = true_bezier_y - pred_bezier_y

    square_sum = np.square(error_x) + np.square(error_y)
    rse = np.sqrt(square_sum)
    mrse = np.mean(rse)
    return mrse
```

Essentially I compute the loss by comparing the bezier curve generated from the true control points and the bezier curve generated by the predicted control points by the tensorflow model.

I keep getting this error:
*true_bezier_x, true_bezier_y = bezier_curve(control_true.numpy())
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'*

So far I have tried to enable **Eager Execution** with `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution` at the beginning of the program. I also tried to evaluate the tensor to then transform it into a nupmy with `out.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())`.

Both attempts have been fruitless and I got the same error as before.

I'm working with Tensorflow version: 2.10.0

Comment: I don't think you want to use `.numpy` in a loss function. That's why you get the error. It's to prevent you from messing up the computational graph.

Comment: What can I do then? Implement a new bezier function that reads the values of the tensor `Tensor("custom_loss/Reshape:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32)` and computes the bezier curve from those or the custom loss should not depend on outside functions?

Comment: Yes, you should use math operations that tensorflow "understands" that will operate on Tensors. Although, it seems like you could calculate the loss directly from the control points without actually creating the curve.